# jquery: extend method with two objects - result is object Object?

Tags: jquery, object, extend, for-in-loop

I'm doing some jQuery tutorial at jQuery.com and try to understand the extend method right now. it works ALMOST.

```
var object1 = {
                apple: 0,
                banana: {weight: 52, price: 100},
                cherry: 97
                };

            var object2 = {
                banana: {price: 200},
                durian: 100
                };

            var obj =   $.extend(object1, object2);

            for(var key in obj) {
                alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + obj[key]);
```

The alert box gives the following output:

- key:apple  value:0
- key:banana value: [object Object]
- key:cherry value: 97
- key:durian value: 100

The second key-value-pair should be banana:200. Can somebody explain why it is not? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The alert box simply doesn't show nested objects.

```
//Use this on your object before you alert
alert(JSON.stringify(myObj));
```

If you use Chrome or Firebug, you can easily see this output using `console.log(myObj)` instead of alert. You would need to see the console by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+J` in Windows.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The bannana is a object poperty. So if you extend it it will be replace by second. But if you want to update the `price` and `weight` properties, you have to code like that

```
var obj = $.extend(true, object1, object2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The object Banana will be:

```
banana : {
  weight: 52,
  price: 200
}
```

`$.extend` will not remove the keys that are not overwritten, it's cleverer than that. So weight still exists.

The reason it shows `[object object]` is because there is no `toString()` method and `alert` doesn't know how to Stringify the banana Object. If you print the values on their own to the console this is what you will see.

Comment: i'm not to sure yet what i did, but i used the code ElGamed suggested and it kind of worked. but actually weight of banana is not in the alert box, just the price 200.

Answer (score 0):

It shows you the object because it is object  and it doesn't dive in deep.

You can easily test it by adding this :

```
object2.banana.toString=function (){ return this["price"]; //only for object2's banana. just for demonstrating.
```

complete code : http://jsbin.com/esobuc/2/edit

```
var object1 = {
                apple: 0,
                banana: {weight: 52, price: 100},
                cherry: 97
                };

            var object2 = {
                banana: {price: 200},
                durian: 100
                };

object2.banana.toString=function (){ return this["price"]; 
}

            var obj =   $.extend(object1, object2);

            for(var key in obj) {
              alert('key: ' + key + '\n' + 'value: ' + obj[key]);}
```

Answer (score 0):

following should help:

```
// override banana with its price
object2.banana = object2.banana.price

// merge both objects
var obj = $.extend(object1, object2);
```